# Filter array of types, based on array of properties in type

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, filtering

I am working in an Angular 9 project (Typescript).

I have an array of strings. I also have an array of a custom type.

How do I filter the array of custom type to only include those whose property match one of the strings in the string array.
Here's some code to help explain:

```
//I declare a custom type
export interface CustomType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}


//I declare my arrays
customTypesArr: CustomType[] = [
    {id: "000", name: "name 1"},
    {id: "001", name: "name 2"},
    {id: "002", name: "name 3"}
];
customTypesNamesArr: string[] = ["name 3", "name 1"];
```

Now I want to create an array from `customTypesArr` that only includes items whose name property is the same as any string in `customTypesNamesArr`.
The end result would be:

```
myNewCustomTypesArr: CustomType[] = [
    {id: "000", name: "name 1"},
    {id: "002", name: "name 3"}
];
```

I'm thinking it would be something like this, but I can't quite hammer it out:

```
customTypesArr.filter(item =>
      customTypesNamesArr.forEach(name => {
        if (name == item.name) {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
```

I'm really not sure on if I should be using `forEach()` in this scenario...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var filtered = customTypesArr.filter(function(item) 
  {
   return customTypesNamesArr.indexOf(item.name) !== -1;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) of arrays to make this pretty simple.

```
customTypesArr.filter(item => customTypesNamesArr.includes(item.name));
```

Basically, just do a filter where you you check to see if each item's name is `include`ed the array of names that are allowed.